# How to ignore a parameter in a prepared mysqli query in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a prepared mysqli query like this:

```
$query = $database->prepare("SELECT * FROM items WHERE inStock > ? AND size < ? AND name LIKE ?");            
$query->bind_param('iis', $inStock, $size, $name);              
$query->execute();
```

There are many various conditions in the WHERE clause which filter out the results. 
The problem is, that those parameters are supplied in a search form and they aren't mandatory. For example, someone can search by using only the name, or only by using the size and name, or by using the size, name and inStock, all at the same time.

I need some way to adjust the query so I can supply only the parameters I want. The only solution I can think of, is to make a huge if..else structure where prepared queries with all combinations of the search options exist, but that is out of the question as there are thousands of combinations.

The only actual realistic solution I can think of, would be to use a not prepared query, where I glue the conditions together with from pieces like `$query .= "AND name LIKE '%".escapestuff($_POST['name'])."%'"`

But that is very ugly and I would very much like to stay with the prepared query system.

Comment: Sounds like a job for.... loops!

Comment: Use a query builder (e.g. Doctrine DBAL)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build up a list of the criteria and add into a list the bind values and types, here is a quick mock up which uses two of the fields you refer to...

```
$data = [];
$params = "";
$where = [];
if ( !empty($name)) {
    $data[] = $name;
    $params.="s";
    $where[] = "name like ?";
}
if ( !empty($size)) {
    $data[] = $size;
    $params.="i";
    $where[] = "size < ?";
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM items";
if ( count($where) > 0 ){
    $sql .= " where ". implode ( " and ", $where);
}
$query = $database->prepare($sql);
$query->bind_param($params, ...$data);
$query->execute();
```

Notice that the `bind_param()` uses the `...` to allow you to pass an array instead of the individual fields.